# Composite foreign key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, database-design

I have a table named Books which contains 3 columns.

```
TableName: Books
Columns: BookId (PK), BookName, Book_Publisher_XRef_Id (FK), IsInternal
```

I have two tables that contains publisher information. Both these tables have different set of columns.

```
TableName: InternalPublishers
Columns: PublisherId (PK), PublisherName, ....

TableName: ExternalPublishers
Columns: PublisherId (PK), PublisherName, ....
```

I have a link table that contains information about which book belongs to which publisher. One book can have multple publishers.

```
TableName: Books_Publishers_XRef
Columns: Book_Publisher_XRef_Id (PK), PublisherId
```

If I want to create a Foreign Key constraint on PublisherId, I need to create sort of Composite Foreign Key constraint which I am not sure can be created.

So in this scenario, what is the best way to achieve FK on PublisherId in Books_Publishers_XRef table?

1. Break Books_Publishers_XRef table in 2 tables i.e. one for Internal Publishers and another one for External Publishers and have 2 columns in Books table for Books_Internal_Publishers_XRef and Books_External_Publishesr_XRef tables?
2. Don't create FK on Publisher_Id column and leave the design as it is?
3. Create composite FK by adding Publisher_Type_Id column in Books table and Books_Publishers_XRef table where if Publisher_Type_Id = 1, it belongs to Internal_Publishers table and Publisher_Type_Id = 2, it belongs to External_Publishers table ? (Not sure if this is possible)
4. Some other schema design?

Please advise.

Comment: Do you really need two tables for Publishers? You could have one table and one extra column specifying if it is internal or external.

Comment: They both have different fields and i am not sure if i shud leave values in some of the fields as NULL based on the PublisherType

Comment: You can have one Publisher table and two more tables with a 1:1 relation to Publisher that contains the specific fields for each publisher type.

Comment: ...or allow columns to be nullable - `NULL` is not the devil. You can even make the nullable constraint dependent on the publisher type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't divide your data amongst two tables: `InternalPublishers`, `ExternalPublishers`.  Create one table and have a `bit` field to determiner whether they are internal or external.  Something like this:

```
create table Publisher
(
    PublisherId int not null primary key clustered,
    PublisherName varchar(100) not null,
    IsInternal bit not null
)
go
```

That way you can easily create your foreign key reference.  After all, you seem to have this same design for `Books`, keep that going to publishers.

Comment: fields in the publisher table are not same for both tables. I will have lots of NULL values in that table based on publishertype

Comment: Only make it a bit column if you know there will never, *ever* be additional Types of publisher some day. (Also, you can't index bit columns, which may be an issue.)

Comment: Classic type/subtype problem. One table for Publisher, then sub-type tables (with subject-specific columns) for Internal and External. Anything else seems like a kludge work-around.

Comment: any reason why should i not break XRef table into two tables like i mentioed as option 1 in my question? Any disadvantage?

Comment: @Asdfg Really ugly queries if you want to run reports or searches that ignore publisher type.

Comment: @PhilipKelley : Excellent solution. Submitted your solution to DBA for review and hoping it to get accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Keep all common columns in the `Publisher` table.
- Subtype tables have only columns specific to each one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have created the tables same way.